# Is using await on the UI thread the same as a blocking call?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

Just reading and thinking aloud: if I used `await` on a call to a method from within the main UI thread, that would tantamount to being a blocking call, right, since there's no thread that called the UI thread?

For example:

```
int Main()
{
    // This would be a blocking call, right?
    await PrintTwoMillionTimes("Hello");

    Console.WriteLine("Phew! Done!");
}
```

Comment: That code does not compile. You cannot use `await` in a method without `async`

Comment: Thank you. I should have finished my reading and practice before I asked this question. Sometimes, I get very curious. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, absolutely not.

The point of `await` is that it *doesn't* block. Assuming the result of `PrintTwoMillionTimes` behaves sensibly, the async method will return immediately... but it will attach a continuation so that the rest of the method will execute (on the UI thread) when the result completes.

So assuming you've got a working example (currently your method declaration isn't `async`, and returns `int`, and you haven't got any `return` statements...) the flow is:

- The async method starts
- `PrintTwoMillionTimes` is called, which would *start* an asynchronous operation, returning something representing the operation (e.g. a `Task`)
- The generated code would check whether the operation has already completed:

  - If it's already completed, execution continues
  - Otherwise, a continuation is attached to the task (or whatever is representing the operation) and the async method returns

If you're returning `Task` or `Task<T>` from the async method, the return value can be used to indicate when the async method itself has completed (i.e. after your `Console.WriteLine` has executed).

This is just a *very* brief description, of course. You should really read up on async/await in more detail. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) is a reasonable starting point.

Comment: I have to admit, I asked this question out of pre-matured curiosity. I'm still in the course of studying this material from the MSDN.

My curiosity at this point is: if PrintTwoMillion (whether or not it returns anything) runs on a background worker thread from the threadpool, then where is the flow-of-control when I call await on it from a UI thread? What's the system doing then? Does the UI thread also get suspended? Or is it freed to take/handle event notifications at this point. I am sure I'll have answers to these questions when I've finished reading. Little curious before I finish. :-)

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: `PrintTwoMillion` *has* to return something, otherwise you can't await it. No, the UI thread doesn't get suspended - it keeps processing events as normal. Then when `PrintTwoMillion` completes, the continuation for the rest of the async method is scheduled on the UI thread. But yes, you should basically keep reading.

Answer (score 5):

No; the whole point of `await` is that it **isn't** a blocking call.
The compiler transforms the code after the `await` into a callback.

As long as the thing you're awaiting is well-behaved (meaning that it won't do its work synchronously), your UI will be fine.

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry I think I asked my question a bit too early.